# recommended books about curve fitting and interpolations ?

Tags: java, statistics, interpolation, curve-fitting

I am working on a java application where i need to do some curve fittings and interpolations. I don't have the theoretical statistical background about that. I appreciate it if anyone can recommend good books covering this topic, but not very advanced ones. If the book provides coding examples in java, it would be greater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to recommend without knowing your mathematics ability, but if you want to understand these concepts you will at the very least require a grasp of linear algebra. I would recommend this book http://www-maths.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~gmp/gmptheo.html . It describes interpolation and approximation and has some sections on splines which you may find useful. It is aimed at an undergraduate mathematics level - some of the chapters may not be useful to you but if nothing else it will at least highlight the concepts that you need to know in order to understand the things you want to know about. If you find this too advanced, (if you do not have A-level maths or the equivalent) then perhaps consider an introductory text on linear algebra as this is probably the most important concept to understand and is central to approximation and interpolation theory. There are also probably a great many good tutorials available online.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of what books to read, but one good place to start would be to look into fitting a [Spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29). However, the variations on this technique are used to model as closely as possible a curve. For example, Dentists might find this technique very useful.

If you are looking for predictive capabilities, [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/LinearRegression.java.html) is an example of how to implement a linear regression. Which, depending on your ultimate goal would be another good place to start.